# MailKit C# SmtpClient.Connect() to smtp.Office365.com throwing exception: "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

Tags: c#, smtp, office365, mailkit

I am using MailKit (version 1.18.0) and getting below error while connecting to SMTP Office 365.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
```

Connect Method:

```
client.Connect("smtp.Office365.com", 587, true);
```

Error Message: *"The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format"*

I searched on the web for this scenario and found that for few people, it got resolve by using useSSL false value. So then I tried passing false for useSSL but got invalid remote certificate error.

```
client.Connect("smtp.Office365.com", 587, false);
```

Error Message: *"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."*

After researching again, found that we should tried different overload method for connect with start TLS.

```
client.Connect("smtp.Office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
```

Error Message: *"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."*

If I run the below powershell from the same server, it's working fine. It's sending email without an issue.

```
$emailFrom = "from@example.com"
$emailto = "to@example.com"
$Subject = "Test SMTP"
$Body = "Test from Server"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SMTPClient($SMTPServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.enablessl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

I tried above things on port 25 as well but got same issues. This issue is occurring only for smtp.Office365.com host using MailKit.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, ch, e) => true;
client.Connect("smtp.Office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please clarify this.  Also if you could tell in which scenario we should use this? I used client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback code before client.Connect("smtp.Office365.com", 587, false); and it worked without an issue.

Comment: The `false` parameter is the same as using `SecureSocketOptions.StartTlsWhenAvailable`.

Comment: Is it advisable to use `client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, ch, e) => true;` in Prod environment? I mean as we are skipping server certificate validation step.

Comment: No, it is not advisable. MailKit 2.11.1, for example, hard-codes the latest certificate info for office365 mail servers and so using `client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, ch, e) => true;` is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is also working using below code.

```
client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, ch, e) => true;
client.Connect("smtp.Office365.com", 587, false);
```